# Why people prefer implicits over inheritence to enrich Dataframes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have a dataframe `df1` which I want to enrich to `df2` by adding columns (which values are deduced from combinations of the original columns), I see 4 options :

```
df2 = Enricher.enrich(df1)
```

I understand that utility classes are too verbose, so the following -more functionnal way- does not have much appeal either :

```
df2 = df1.map(Enricher.enrich(_))
```

I feel like the Eldorado of syntax looks more like this :

```
df2 = df1.enrich
```

And I see two ways to accomplish that :

- inheritence: `CustomerInfos extends Dataframe`, in which i create the method `enrich`, which has the effect of making `df1` and `df2` instances of a custom class `CustomerInfos`
- implicits: basically `import Enricher.implicits._` to have my `enrich` method magically appear in `df1`

I can even imagine the following, which I have seen used mostly for DTO classes :

```
df1 = CustomerInfosDf("path/to/df")
df2 = df1(enrich=true)
```

Why is it that everyone and every example I find avoid inheritance like the black plague? Why bearing implicits until the end of the scope when the enricher is only used for one use case on one specific dataframe? Is this a performance question I am not aware of or is it just to show off mad spark skills?

Comment: FWIW I prefer the humble static helper method.

Answer (score 2):

Please see if below points help you -

- There’s a fundamental difference between your own code and libraries of
  other people: you can change or extend your own code as you wish, but if
  you want to use someone else’s libraries, you usually have to take them as
  they are. For example, String class is part of JDK and it has been declared 'final' hence can not be inherited/customized. If you want to enrich it - inheritance can't help you and only 'implicit' construct can.
- Also I believe - implicit avoids cluttering and ambiguity. For example - if you want to persist your RDD to cassandra , you do not need to look 
  for any other specific version of 'RDD' class. You can simply invoke rdd.saveToCassandra. This helps the end users of the API a great deal.

Implicit is a construct of scala language not of spark framework. However Spark community is leveraging it in a great way.